# How to load second view ,that can see the first view thourgh it (transparent), in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-ui-automation

This is my question,think that I have two views. in the first view there is a imageview(with a image) and a button.When I press the button then it load second view(with storyboard segue kind is present modally).when that view loads, I want to set the first view,  through the second view(should be transparent).

I tried with setting secondview's defatul view `background color` to `default` but it gives black.how can I do that.

Comment: then don't use separate second view controller , instead use UIView and make it transparent

Comment: yep, I know do like that, but I asked to know is there a way to do that. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i fixed you issue after a few minutes test...
I found that segue has a property named presentation,like this:
[image]

you may change the property to Over Current Context and it works

Comment: you can see [Present a transparent modal UIViewController]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260774/present-a-transparent-modal-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Select your secondviewcontroller goto attribute inspector then select Transition style to 'cover vertical' and presentation to 'over current context'

and write the code for presentviewcontroller to present your second view controller modally in firstviewcontroller.

Comment: where to write code for `presentviewcontrller`  thing, I'm getting a problem @sanjeet

Comment: at the place of click event

Comment: @snjeet, I'm passing values from `second view` to `firstview`, if the segue `presentation` is `over current context` it does not update the first view's values with which I passed. but segue `presentation` is any other, it works fine.why is that.

Comment: You can use Delegate.

Comment: before the second view will present .The App will call the function(- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender) in firstView if you implement it.You can set a segue identify in storyboard and check it in this function .Get the Second view instance and do what you wanna do. if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {
        ViewController1 *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setDelegate:self];
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can add the view of one viewcontroller to another as a subview. This way the code for each viewcontroller is in it's own class, but they are displayed on top of each other.

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[viewControllerA.view setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```