# How to create Onboarding/WalkThrough/ App-intro screen like this swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, walkthrough

i want to create Onboarding / Walkthrough screens in swift but my screens are transparent , i need to create each image of this screens with transparent background or better way to do this , please tell me better way to this.[image: First image],[image: Second Image],[image: Third Image],[image: Fourth Image]
I want transparent background also. Suggest me better way for this.

Comment: you can create a perticular UIView for each design. give black colour as backgroundColour with 0.7 or 0.8 alpha . and finally add this view in any class you want.

Comment: yes but i also want background tables and details view as background , can i ask for designer to give me that table view image as background or what? @GOPALVASANI

Comment: you just make your view semi transparent

Comment: can you tell how can i add other controller on uiview @Lu_

Comment: you can create your own views with all the features or check these links : https://github.com/ephread/Instructions and https://github.com/yukiasai/Minamo

Comment: no @Asmita , if you are giving the black colour with minimum alpha  as bgColor and when you are add those Views inside any class , you can easilly see the background Views.

Comment: @Asmita Refer to library [here](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions)

Comment: i am created pageviewcontroller for this how i should i set for that pageview controller bgcolor with minimum alpa i get other view controller as backround @GOPALVASANI

Comment: No need to create another UIViewController For this type of functionality , just Create a one UIView , add CollectionView and Pagecontrol inside the View and add those view in any class you want .

Comment: combination of collectionView and pageControl is very easy although @Asmita

Comment: @GOPALVASANI can you help in this please

Comment: its a long task @Asmita

Comment: i mean i can't give you instruction on a stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Present a transparent modal UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260774/present-a-transparent-modal-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: Follow @Amit solution. I also work with Instructions. Yes, it is a hassle to setup and may take some time to get comfortable with the system. But trust me, it is way faster than making a good walkthrough on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an UIViewController with a UIScrollView and a pagination (scrollView pagination enabled and a pageControl). Your different tutorial views are defined inside each page in the scrollView.

the key part here is to set modalPresentationStyle of your modal controller to .overCurrentContext when you call it :

```
let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewController") as! MyViewController
VC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
VC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```